# Authenticating google cloud api on android

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables

I'm using the Google Cloud Speech-to-text API, within my android app.

How would one authenticate to the API without the ability to set the necessary environment variable?

I've not been able to find any documentation covering authenticating on android, with the environment variable, and file

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but I think you're trying to use a service account ("file") and perhaps `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` ("environment variable") to authenticate your app.

You should not.

Service Accounts are best applied to software (e.g. another service) that's running autonomously (i.e. not directly by a human user) that needs to authenticate with a Google API.

For an Android App, I think you probably wish to authenticate the human user of your app against the Google API using the full OAuth flow were your user is prompted to approve use of the Google API and then, your application is authenticated as this user.

See here for an explanation of the 3 primary authentication methods:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/

See here for an overview of authenticating a human user to a Google API:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user

See here -- less confident in this as I've not used it -- as a way to authenticate Android apps using Google Sign-In (i.e. OAuth):
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

HTH

Comment: I was indeed looking at some service account documentation, but I'm now using a simple API key - which suffices, no oauth required. Still... there's no documentation about how to use the key with the API, in java. You can use the key within a HTTP request with a simple get parameter. `.../?key=API_KEY`

Comment: See here: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys. OAuth is likely a better choice. It's more work but it's more secure and it's more appropriate because it entails your users granting your app permission to their data (being used by the API). API Keys require more careful management. While you may restrict the use of API Keys, anyone with one of your keys can use an API that is being billed to you.

Comment: My problem is applying the key in the context of the android application. I'd read the documentation you've posted

Comment: I assume you're using Java? The documentation says that the Cloud Client Libraries don't support Android (https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries). I'm insufficiently familiar with Android development to be much help. But, if that's true, you'd need to use the API Client Library (https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/speech/v1/java/latest/) but this library doesn't support auth'ing with API Keys (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/dev-guide#authentication)